# Coded UI Test Unable to Open Private Mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2015, coded-ui-tests

The coded ui Test in VS 2015 I have generated looks like:

```
    [GeneratedCode("Coded UITest Builder", "14.0.23107.0")]
    public class UINewtabInternetExplorWindow : BrowserWindow
    {



  public UINewtabInternetExplorWindow()
    {
        #region Search Criteria
        this.SearchProperties[UITestControl.PropertyNames.Name] = "New tab";
        this.SearchProperties[UITestControl.PropertyNames.ClassName] = "IEFrame";
        this.WindowTitles.Add("New tab");
        this.WindowTitles.Add("Certificate Error: Navigation Blocked");
        this.WindowTitles.Add("Home - Select Service");
        this.WindowTitles.Add("Sign in to your account");
        this.WindowTitles.Add("Home");
        #endregion
    }

    public void LaunchUrl(System.Uri url)
    {
        this.CopyFrom(BrowserWindow.Launch(url)); // Can't Add -private
    }
```

I know that [if you pass the "-private" parameter to the launch function](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/12256/coded-ui-how-to-launch-website-in-ie-inprivate-browsing-mode) you can open IE in private mode. But I can't !!!

I can't because the launch function has no such overloaded function. Is there any way I can test my UI in private mode only each time. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I dont have a direct approach. But this hack should help you get what you want..

```
// Start the Browser As Process to start in Private mode 
        Process browserProcess = new Process();
        browserProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "iexplore.exe";            
        browserProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "-private";
        browserProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;

        // Start browser
        browserProcess.Start();
        // Get Process (Browser) Handle 
        Int64 browserHandle =  browserProcess.Handle.ToInt64();


        // Create a new Browser Instance & Assign the browser created as process using the window Handle
        BrowserWindow browserFormHandle = new BrowserWindow();
        browserFormHandle.SearchProperties.Add(BrowserWindow.PropertyNames.WindowHandle, browserFormHandle.ToString());

        browserFormHandle.NavigateToUrl(new Uri("http://www.google.com"));
```